# Autokill broken reverse ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have 1 server which is behind a NAT and a firewall and I have another in another location that is accessible via a domain. The server behind the NAT and firewall is running on a cloud environment and is designed to be disposable ie if it breaks we can simply redeploy it with a single script, in this case, it is OpenStack using a heat template. When that server fires up it runs the following command to create a reverse SSH tunnel to the server outside the NAT and Firewall to allow us to connect via port 8080 on that server. The issue I am having is it seems if that OpenSSH tunnel gets broken (server goes down maybe) the tunnel remains, meaning when we re-deploy the heat template to launch the server again it will no longer be able to connect to that port unless I kill the ssh process on the server outside the NAT beforehand.

here is the command I am using currently to start the reverse tunnel:

```
sudo ssh -f -N -T -R 9090:localhost:80 user@example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and fixed it this way:

First, at the server, I created in the home directory a script called `.kill_tunel_ssh.sh` with this contents:

```sh
#this finds the process that is opening the port 9090, finds its PID and kills it
sudo netstat -ltpun | grep 9090 | grep 127 | awk -F ' ' '{print $7}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Then, at the client, I created a script called `connect_ssh.sh` with this contents:

```sh
#this opens a ssh connection, runs the script .kill_tunnel_ssh.sh and exit
ssh user@remote.com "./.kill_tunel_ssh.sh"

#this opens a ssh connection opening the reverse tunnel
ssh user@remote.com -R 9090:localhost:80
```

Now, I always use `connect_ssh.sh` to open the SSH connection, instead of using the ssh command directly.

It requires the `user` at the remote host to have `sudo` configured without asking for password when executing the `netstat` command.

Maybe (probably) there is a better way to accomplish it, but that is working for me.